# Send Email using SMTP via gmail

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-core, smtp

I'm working in ASP.Net Core and trying to send email using smtp client from gmail. Have following code but it's not working
Have seen following post as well but it doesn't work
http://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-send-emails-from-aspnet-core/

It thorws following error

> System.NotSupportedException: The SMTP server does not support authentication

```
var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("From Name", "fromEmail@gmail.com"));
emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("To Name", "toEmail@gmail.com"));
emailMessage.Subject = subject;

var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = message;
emailMessage.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

var client = new SmtpClient();
try
{
    await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com", 25, SecureSocketOptions.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");  
    await client.AuthenticateAsync("fromEmail@gmail.com", "fromPassword"); //error occurs here

    await client.SendAsync(emailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
    await client.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

Comment: Why are you using port 25 when the example shows port 587?

Comment: @mason point is correct. We can use 587 or 465 port id In gmail smtp!. I don't know why you are using 25.

Answer (score 0):

The `NotSupportedException` is thrown because GMail does not support authentication without using an SSL/TLS connection because it only supports non-encrypted password-based authentication mechanisms.

I would recommend connecting like this:

```
client.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls)
```

Hope that helps.